# MySqlConnection is not working

Tags: c#, mysql

I have seen a tutorial using `MySqlConnection variable name = new MySqlConnection(connection string);`

But When I type the above code in Visual Studio Express 2013, it(`MySqlConnection`) does not become blue.
And it says `The type or namespace MySqlConnection could not be found`.
I have searched Google but I got nothing.Can someone help?
Sorry for this dumb question but I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: _Well_, looks like you need to add reference to `MySql.Data.dll`. Also you can add this `dll` as package by using [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Mysql.Data/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to download and reference an MySQL connector to your VS project .

Look at this link: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

After you add the reference, add following using to your class:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

Then your code should work.